# Jquery jscrollpane width to adjust automatically according to content

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I am looking to use jScrollPane on my new website and am having some troubleshooting problems with it. Searched up and down for answers but couldn't find any.

Please take a look at the website here: http://www.giamarescotti.com/v2

Instead of specifying a definite width to .scroll-pane, I would like it to expand according to the content because it's impossible for me to keep recalculating the width as I update my website regularly.

*Due to being a new user, I am unable to post images and codes. Please view the source file at the website.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much!

Regards, 
 Dave

Comment: Updated my answer again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this could be what you are looking for. The demo here shows you how to autoReinitialise the width of a container if the content inside of it changes.

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/dynamic_content.html

Or if you are setting the width of the container as a percentage, take a look at this demo

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/dynamic_width.html

Try replacing your current jScrollPane JS with the code below

```
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({
    showArrows: true,
    autoReinitialise: true
});
```

Hope that helps

**UPDATE:**

Hmmmmm I don't have much time right now, but you could do a really simple bit of jQuery to calculate the width for you...

Then remove the *p* tag from around your images and replace it with a *div* tag that has an ID that refers back to the above JS. (By the way a *p* tag is a Paragraph tag, for text!)

Lastly set a fall back width in your CSS so that people without JS don't see loads of images going down the page.

A better fix that uses only CSS should really be found, I'll look into later if I get time!

**2nd UPDATE**

Right, lets sort that 1-3% of final details out :)

The margin of 5 was just a rough guide as the browsers themselves are adding a margin/padding to your images. Let's add a fixed 5px margin to each image apart from the last one.

Your JS would be mostly the same, except that you will need to -5 from the calculated total width because we will be removing the 5px margin from the last image.

```
var totalImages = $("#images img").length;
var imgWidth = 452 + 5; //width of an image plus the margin
$("#imagesContainer").css("width",totalImages*imgWidth - 5);

$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({
    showArrows: true,
    autoReinitialise: true
});
```

Next we will give a class to your last image in the list called *lastImage* like so

```
<div id="imagesContainer">
    <img src="images/food.jpg" />
    <img src="images/food.jpg" />
    <img src="images/food.jpg" />
    <img src="images/food.jpg" />
    <img class="lastImage" src="images/food.jpg" />
</div>
```

Now the CSS

```
#imagesContainer {
width:5000px; /*fallback width*/
overflow:hidden;
}

#imagesContainer img {
display:block;
margin:0 5px 0 0; /*adding a 5px margin to the right*/
padding:0;
float:left;
}

.lastImage {
margin-right:0 !important; /*removing the margin right from the last img*/
}
```

Now each image has a 5px space between it. IF you wanted no margin then just change *margin:0 5px 0 0;* to *margin:0;*, remove the lastImage class and CSS and remove the *+5* and *-5* from the JS!

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Mac,
Thank you for your advice. It's not what I'm looking for but I did find a good use for autoReinitialise =)
If you look at the source code, you will find the following line:
<p style="width: 3000px;">
That is what I want to change. Instead of specifying a fixed width, I would like it to be able to expand as needed as I add more images. I'm not even sure if the images need to be within a <p> tag.
Thanks again!

Comment: Dear Mac, this works very closely to what I am trying to achieve! There is just this 1-3% left in the details that isn't perfect (yet). I don't have an inkling on programming, jScrollPane is a nice feature I found that I want to incorporate.
When I try to change the padding/margin to anything under 5 [var imgWidth = 452 + 5;] the images starts scrolling vertically. I also noticed that the margin/padding is applied at the end of the last image only. I added a red border so that you may see it for yourself too.
I appreciate your help very much on this. Thank you! =) * new files uploaded.