# jquery scrollpane auto reinitialise width;

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm using this http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ (also see: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/image.html)

I have a series of images that I want available to the viewer via a horizontal scroll bar. There is an auto-reinitialise property available with the jscrollpane, however im not sure if this is working properly

1. It waits for some of the images to load and then shows the scrollbar [is it possible to show this instantly, initially?]
2. If you start scrolling before all the images are loaded, the pane width is not accurate and you cant scroll to all the images

My link : http://iamjpg.com/photo/test.html

Reference: [width within Jquery jscrollpane to accommodate different width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715554/width-within-jquery-jscrollpane-to-accomodate-different-width)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width and height in the image tag directly

```
<img src="image.jpg" width="100" height="50" alt="" />
```

Or you can initialize your jscrollpane when the window finished loading.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.class').jscrollPane();
})
```

I would go with solution 1 but if you don't have the width/height then solution 2 can also work.
If you're loading images through ajax, you will need to call the reinitialise function from the API (http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/api.html).

Hope this helps!